# SQL DATEDIFF in a SELECT Statement ')' Error

Tags: sql, reporting-services, casting, datediff

I have currently been placed in charge of an SSRS instance and am running into a little bit of trouble with one of my select statements. Essentially, what I would like to do is take the time that a ticket has been received and subtract the time it was completed in order to figure out the total duration of a ticket.

The problem it seems that I'm running into is with DATEDIFF. The two fields in question (`IS_RECEIVED_DATETIME` + `RESOLVED`) are both `Float(14)` fields within the database. So I am attempting to convert the fields in order to datediff them. Currently, I am receiving a ')' error on the line that I have in bold. have done everything I can think of to remove a ) and correct the error, but all seem to be closed and in the right place. Any suggestions or tips would be GREATLY appreciated!!!!

And this is my first post here, so please let me know if You need some more info, or if I am filing this incorrectly. Thanks ahead of time!

Here is my Select Statement Instance -

```
,DATEDIFF(Day,CONVERT(datetime,LEFT(CAST(CAST(ISSUES.IS_RECEIVED_DATETIME as BIGINT) as VARCHAR(14)),4)+'/'+
SUBSTRING(CAST(CAST(ISSUES.IS_RECEIVED_DATETIME as BIGINT) as VARCHAR(14)),5,2) +'/'+
SUBSTRING(CAST(CAST(ISSUES.IS_RECEIVED_DATETIME as BIGINT) as VARCHAR(14)),7,2)+' '+
SUBSTRING(CAST(CAST(ISSUES.IS_RECEIVED_DATETIME as BIGINT) as VARCHAR(14)),9,2)+':'+
**SUBSTRING(CAST(CAST(ISSUES.IS_RECEIVED_DATETIME as BIGINT) as VARCHAR(14)),11,2)+':'+**
SUBSTRING(CAST(CAST(ISSUES.IS_RECEIVED_DATETIME as BIGINT) as VARCHAR(14)),13,2)+':'+) 
,CONVERT(datetime,LEFT(CAST(CAST(ISSUES.IS_RESOLVED_DATETIME as BIGINT) as VARCHAR(14)),4)+'/'+
SUBSTRING(CAST(CAST(ISSUES.IS_RESOLVED_DATETIME as BIGINT) as VARCHAR(14)),5,2) +'/'+
SUBSTRING(CAST(CAST(ISSUES.IS_RESOLVED_DATETIME as BIGINT) as VARCHAR(14)),7,2)+' '+
SUBSTRING(CAST(CAST(ISSUES.IS_RESOLVED_DATETIME as BIGINT) as VARCHAR(14)),9,2)+':'+
SUBSTRING(CAST(CAST(ISSUES.IS_RESOLVED_DATETIME as BIGINT) as VARCHAR(14)),11,2)+':'+
SUBSTRING(CAST(CAST(ISSUES.IS_RESOLVED_DATETIME as BIGINT) as VARCHAR(14)),13,2))) as 'DURATION'
```

Comment: What values are in the fields?

Answer (score 1):

The specific error you're getting is because of the '+)' combination at the end of the line *after* the one you marked.

Whether there's a better approach to accomplish what you're doing is another question, which we might be able to answer if we saw the content of your fields.

Answer (score 1):

There is a `+` too much in your statement just before the second convert:

```
,DATEDIFF(Day,CONVERT(datetime,LEFT(CAST(CAST(ISSUES.IS_RECEIVED_DATETIME as BIGINT) as VARCHAR(14)),4)+'/'+
SUBSTRING(CAST(CAST(ISSUES.IS_RECEIVED_DATETIME as BIGINT) as VARCHAR(14)),5,2) +'/'+
SUBSTRING(CAST(CAST(ISSUES.IS_RECEIVED_DATETIME as BIGINT) as VARCHAR(14)),7,2)+' '+
SUBSTRING(CAST(CAST(ISSUES.IS_RECEIVED_DATETIME as BIGINT) as VARCHAR(14)),9,2)+':'+
SUBSTRING(CAST(CAST(ISSUES.IS_RECEIVED_DATETIME as BIGINT) as VARCHAR(14)),11,2)+':'+
SUBSTRING(CAST(CAST(ISSUES.IS_RECEIVED_DATETIME as BIGINT) as VARCHAR(14)),13,2)+':') 
,CONVERT(datetime,LEFT(CAST(CAST(ISSUES.IS_RESOLVED_DATETIME as BIGINT) as VARCHAR(14)),4)+'/'+
SUBSTRING(CAST(CAST(ISSUES.IS_RESOLVED_DATETIME as BIGINT) as VARCHAR(14)),5,2) +'/'+
SUBSTRING(CAST(CAST(ISSUES.IS_RESOLVED_DATETIME as BIGINT) as VARCHAR(14)),7,2)+' '+
SUBSTRING(CAST(CAST(ISSUES.IS_RESOLVED_DATETIME as BIGINT) as VARCHAR(14)),9,2)+':'+
SUBSTRING(CAST(CAST(ISSUES.IS_RESOLVED_DATETIME as BIGINT) as VARCHAR(14)),11,2)+':'+
SUBSTRING(CAST(CAST(ISSUES.IS_RESOLVED_DATETIME as BIGINT) as VARCHAR(14)),13,2))) as 'DURATION'
```

And now grab yourself an editor which can do paren hilightning.